# How to deal with hyper control warrior as an aggressive deck

Tags: hearthstone

In my most recent pursuit of getting lvl 60 in each class and working on golden heroes for each class, I find it is fastest to level up and get quick wins using hyper aggressive strategies (rush rogue, face hunter, zoo, etc.).

Even though the strategy of aggro decks seems easy (hit face and sometimes win), I find there are a lot of beneficial trades you can make and styles of play that can completely counter the opponent and/or force them to make bad trades to deal with your onslaught.

The one deck that seems to elude this strategy is the ultra-control warrior. My matchups against other decks with hyper strategies are quite favourable, but if I meet a warrior on ladder as an aggro rogue, it's almost a guaranteed loss. They are able to deal with my early threats and gain armour at the same time. At the end of the day there just isn't a way to keep up with their armour gain.

Just wondering if anyone has specific strategies they use to combat the control warrior matchup as an aggressive deck. While I don't expect to win most of the time (their deck is designed to deal with this type of aggressive strategy), my personal performance against this class in particular is quite poor when I'm playing aggressive decks (particularly aggro rogue).

Edit: Rank is usually around 3 to legend. I do care about rank and am not purely looking for just volume of wins.

Answer (score 11):

On a generalized level, you're asking how to beat something that counters aggresive decks, while playing aggresive decks. Which, in a *'perfect'* world, shouldn't happen.

I do have two sidepoints before talking about the extremely advanced aggresive tactics you can use;

**1. Alternative**

Since you just asked about "aggresive decks", and not your specific rogue deck, I believe Tempo Mage can do well against control warrior, but it's not the ultra aggresive deck (unless you get perfect wyrmWyrmCoinMirror (counter weps) + cheap spells opener) - Maybe Mana Addict would make it more aggresive.

**2. Survive to live another day**

You didn't mention anything about rank - If rank is irrelevant to you, the easiest solution is to just concede and quickly get to the next fight. Honestly, it's the best option against any deck that just intends to prolong the game forever! It's better to get 2-3 games with decent probability of winning, than hoping you might win that one game.

.

To answer the "main point" of your question... What strategies to use?

Go face.

Hard.

Go more face.

[image]

And hope he doesn't have brawl.

Honestly, unless you dominate the board, his face AND he doesn't have aoe, you shouldn't win. You need him to draw bad.

... If someone has a better *reliable* strategy, I'd **LOVE** to hear it.

Comment: Should've mentioned, but rank is important and I'm usually somewhere between rank 3 and legend. The obvious answer is to just hit face and hope for the best, but I was more asking for specific strategies that force a bad trade for the control opponent (throwing down divine shield threats and forcing them to blow weapon charges or holding off on flooding the board for a specific card to be used, etc.), For these unfavourable matchups it is mostly just getting incremental advantages and hoping they don't draw clinch cards (like the upgraded hero power).

Comment: +1 - I think this hits on many of the key issues. As an aggro deck, a slower, control focused deck is pretty much the worst matchup for you. If you have to play against specific decks, you have to work around their powerful removal, which is very difficult. There's a lot of finesse involved.

Comment: @SethChalmers You could add in tech cards for control, but it also makes your overall strength vs. other decks weaker. The cards would have to be useful against more than just control, which most decks online already take into account. In regards to strategies; yes in a slower matchup, you can commit on the board to force a brawl, without overcommitting - But as a "super rush", you don't have this luxury. Aggro shaman can avoid some of this... Insane possible openers, Feral Spirit and pesky totems (eat weapons), high hp minions and plenty of spells that aren't affected by most defensive cards

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed this is a very unfavorable match-up. In order to have much hope you need to have a great starting hand (mulligan aggressively for your best 1-2 drops) and a great draw. So then your your best course is to just play assuming that you will get the draws you need and go full face. You need to do this because he will be hitting armor up every turn, and every turn you stall by making a trade is more HP you have to burn through. The only exceptions for trade/removal I can think of offhand are armorsmith and acolyte, as both of those can punish you severely with armor and draw respectively.